# Retrieve arraylist from jsonobject

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I'm new to android and I need help in retrieving `ArrayList` from a `JSONObject` and adding an element to it. I have an json object X which is of the form `{'a':[],'b':[],...}`. where `[ ]` represents an `ArrayList` of 'B's  which I have defined. I want to add an element to one of the `ArrayList` present in X.

I have done:

```
B temp = new B();
x.get("string").add(B)
```

This is the Error:

> (176, 31) error: incompatible types
>   required: ArrayList
>   found:    Object

Thanks!

Comment: that thing is known as Json Array not arraylist

Comment: So is an array of B's same as an JSONarray? @Vivek

Comment: no it is different than normal array

Comment: try searching for how to parse json response in android

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve array-list from the JSON because JSON is a human readable type of data. you can do like this:

```
ArrayList<B> list = new ArrayList();
B b= new B();
b.setB(x.getString("Key"));
list.add(b);

b.set("");  is a method could be in your class to set the value of B
x.getString(""); is for getting String type value from the JSON on a specified key
```

Comment: So what is the best method to store multiple arraylists, ? @warlock .Thanks!

Comment: @sairam What do you mean by multiple arraylists, can you give a example

Comment: Lets consider posts and comments as the example.Each post has unique set of comments.So here an arraylist consists of comments for a particular post and the key is the id of the post.